# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

Anyone Please help....

Error -

> Input string was not in a correct format.

```
int comboxchoice = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

i am using below code

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MANISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            tbl = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(tbl);
            comboBox1.DataSource = tbl;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName;
      }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MANISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select name from table1 where id=@id", conn);
            int comboxchoice = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",comboxchoice);
             SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "table1");
            textBox1.Text = ds.Tables["table1"].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
           }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()` exactly? Debug and tell us.

Comment: The value of comboBox1 is `null` or maybe is not an integer number

Comment: DataView = {System.Data.DataView}

Comment: By the sounds of your last comment dataview doesn't have a to string override, does it have a value property?

Comment: @user3488317 NO! I assume you use Visual Studio, put a breakpoint on that line and press `F10`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx#BKMK_Break_into_code__step_or_run_through_code__set_the_next_statement_to_execute

Comment: my filed id is int type in database. Form2 load code working fine and id no successfully showing in combobox.

Comment: the error is simple. it cannot parse the value you give it because it is not a full integer (numeric) value. never guess that everything will be ok with user inputs, always validate before proceeding to do your logic.

Comment: i given id no. value is 1,2,3

Comment: Have you set the `ValueMember` on your combobox?

Comment: yes  comboBox1.ValueMember = tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName;

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see which method you do need but the error you are receiving is because `SelectedValue` is returning a `DataView` (according to your comment).

According to the [Msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) for `DataView`, under ToString,

> Returns a String containing the name of the Component

As a start you can try casting

```
(DataView)comboBox.SelectedValue
```

But this should include extra error handling to ensure that SelectedValue is a valid DataView.

---

As a side note, you ccould also avoid this with better number parsing

```
int comboChoice;
if(int.TryParse((DataView)comboBox.SelectedValue, out comboChoice))
   //Do something
else
    //Number invalid, do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `comboBox1.SelectedValue` is not returning a correct integer value.

You success to change `comboBox1.SelectedValue` to string, but the string cannot convert to corresponding integer because **it is not integer**.

For example, the following statement triggers same error

```
        //non-integer
        string omg = "2313asd";
        int convertedINT = Int32.Parse(omg.ToString());
```

Get idea from @Vignesh Kumar, **empty string** is not recognize as integer format also.

```
        //empty string
        string omg = "";
        int convertedINT = Int32.Parse(omg.ToString());
```

If you confirm only empty string triggers your error , then only check for the empty string with `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`

if you want to eliminate the error **totally**, then confirm your `comboBox1.SelectedValue` is correct integer format with `Int32.TryParse()`.

```
        int comboxchoice;
        if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out comboxchoice))
        {
            proceed by using comboxchoice as converted int value
        }
        else
        {
            //not integer value.....
        }
```

or Maybe you can display the string can check if it is integer value as you imagine

```
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: debug this code it's showing "not interger value " after one error coming here textBox1.Text = ds.Tables["table1"].Rows[1]["name"].ToString();                                          Error- There is no row at position 1. .                          int comboxchoice;
                  if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out comboxchoice))
                 {
                          MessageBox.Show("Interger Value");
                  }
                else
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("not integer value.....");
              }

Comment: it means ds.Tables["table1"].Rows[1] does not exist?

Comment: i meant is it `null` or `DBNull.Value`? you have to ensure your content before converting...

Answer (score -1):

Can't you get rid of the "ToString()". I believe the "SelectedValue" itself is a string value.

Comment: No..SelectedValue is string only

Comment: Int32.Parse only accept string argument but not object